# Material UI Autocomplete component (React)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

Material UI Autocomplete component (React) - I am working on Autocomplete component that will not show any option values by default until you type in a value in React. All the examples I saw in https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/ display options values on key focus. Does anyone know how I can achieve this? I only want the matching option values to show when user start typing the value my code below:

```
import { Autocomplete, TextField } from '@mui/material';

const TestAutoComplete = () => {

  const top100Films = [
    { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
    { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
    { title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },
    { title: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 },
    { title: '12 Angry Men', year: 1957 },
    { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
    { title: 'Pulp Fiction', year: 1994 }
  ]

  const flatProps = {
    options: top100Films.map((option) => option.title),
  };

return (
  <Autocomplete
        {...flatProps}
        id="flat-demo"
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params}  label="Movie" />
        )}
      />
)
};

export default TestAutoComplete;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a condition to render the options only after typing some value, something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Autocomplete, TextField } from '@mui/material';

const TestAutoComplete = () => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  const top100Films = [
    { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
    { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
    { title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },
    { title: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 },
    { title: '12 Angry Men', year: 1957 },
    { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
    { title: 'Pulp Fiction', year: 1994 }
  ]
   
  return (
    <Autocomplete
       inputValue={value}
       onInputChange={(event, newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
       options={
         value.length > 0
           ? top100Films.map(option => option.title)
           : []
       }
       id="flat-demo"
       renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
     />
  )
};

export default TestAutoComplete;
```